# TS/Node.js: Getting the absolute path of the class instance rather than the class itself

Tags: node.js, typescript

Is there a way to get the path (__dirname) of the file where an instance of a class was made without passing that into the constructor?
For example,

```
// src/classes/A.ts
export class A {
    private instanceDirname: string;
    constructor() {
        this.instanceDirname = ??
    }
}

// src/index.ts
import { A } from "./classes/A"
const a = new A();
// a.instanceDirname === __dirname ✓
```

I tried [callsite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/callsite), it worked but I had to do some regex that I'm not happy with to get what I need, I also tried a module called [caller-callsite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/caller-callsite), but that ended up returning the module path, not the path of the file where the instance was made.
Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have callers pass in the location information. Sniffing this stuff seems like a code smell to me (pardon the pun). ;-)

But you *can* do it, by using regular expressions on the V8 call stack from an `Error` instance, but it still involves doing regular expressions (which you didn't like with callsite), though it's doing them on V8's own stacks, which aren't likely to change in a breaking way (and certainly won't except when you do upgrades of Node.js, so it's easy to test). See comments:

```
// A regular expression to look for lines in this file (A.ts / A.js)
const rexThisFile = /\bA\.[tj]s:/i;

// Your class
export class A {
    constructor() {
        // Get a stack trace, break into lines -- this is V8, we can rely on the format
        const stackLines = (new Error().stack).split(/\r\n|\r|\n/);
        // Find the first line that doesn't reference this file
        const line = stackLines.find((line, index) => index > 0 && !rexThisFile.test(line));
        if (line) {
            // Found it, extract the directory from it
            const instanceOfDirName = line.replace(/^\s*at\s*/, "")
                         .replace(/\w+\.[tj]s[:\d]+$/, "")
                         .replace(/^file:\/\//, "");
            console.log(`instanceOfDirName = "${instanceOfDirName}"`);
        }
    }
}
```

Those three replaces can be combined:

```
const instanceOfDirName = line.replace(/(?:^\s*at\s*(?:file:\/\/)?)|(?:\w+\.[tj]s[:\d]+$)/g, "");
```

...but I left them separate for clarity; not going to make any performance difference to care about.

Comment: Close to what I did with callsite, except that in some cases the stack contained null entries which ticked me off, but I guess it could be avoided using V8 directly.. Thanks :)